# Trying to dynamically compile a list of CIDRs for an AWS S3 policy. Expression works in console but fails in plan

Tags: amazon-s3, terraform, policy

Trying to compile a dynamic list of CIDRs to add to an S3 policy, but even though the expression I use seem to work fine in the terraform console they are not accepted by terraform plan.

I've tried to serve it as JSON or as a list, didn't work. The only thing that did, was either passing the list manually or compiling a string like shown below.
Am I missing something here?

### LIST

```
jsonencode(split(",", join(",", formatlist("%s/32", var.web_ips), list(var.vpc_cidr), var.allowed_sources, formatlist("%s/32", list(var.vpn_ip)))))

split(",", join(",", formatlist("%s/32", var.web_ips), list(var.vpc_cidr), var.allowed_sources, formatlist("%s/32", list(var.vpn_ip))))

list(jsonencode(split(",", join(",", formatlist("%s/32", var.web_ips), list(var.vpc_cidr), var.allowed_sources, formatlist("%s/32", list(var.vpn_ip))))))
```

### STRING

```
jsonencode(join(",", formatlist("%s/32", var.web_ips), list(var.vpc_cidr), var.allowed_sources, formatlist("%s/32", list(var.vpn_ip))))
```

Here is the config I'm using:

```
terraform --version
Terraform v0.11.14
+ provider.aws v2.12.0
+ provider.template v2.1.2
```

### vars.tf

```
variable "web_ips" {
  type = "list"
  default = []
}
variable "allowed_sources" {
  type = "list"
  default = []
}
variable "vpn_ip" {}
variable "vpc_cidr" {}
```

### uat.tfvars

```
web_ips = [
  "10.10.0.1"
]
allowed_sources = [
  "10.0.0.1/32",
  "10.0.0.2/32"
]
vpc_cidr = "10.0.0.0/16"
vpn_ip = "10.11.0.1"
```

### app.tf

```
locals {
ips1 = "${jsonencode(split(",", join(",", formatlist("%s/32", var.web_ips), list(var.vpc_cidr), var.allowed_sources, formatlist("%s/32", list(var.vpn_ip)))))}"
ips2 = "${split(",", join(",", formatlist("%s/32", var.web_ips), list(var.vpc_cidr), var.allowed_sources, formatlist("%s/32", list(var.vpn_ip))))}"
}

resource "aws_s3_bucket_policy" "bucket" {
  bucket = "${aws_s3_bucket.bucket.id}"

  policy = <<POLICY
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Id": "Policy00000000000",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Sid": "Stmt00000000000",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Principal": "*",
            "Action": "s3:*",
            "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::bucket/*",
            "Condition": {
                "IpAddress": {
                    "aws:SourceIp": ${local.ips}
              }
            }
        },
        {
            "Sid": "Stmt00000000000",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Principal": "*",
            "Action": "s3:*",
            "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::bucket/*",
            "Condition": {
                "StringEquals": {
                    "aws:SourceVpc": "vpc-XXXXXXXXXXX"
                }
            }
        }
    ]
}
POLICY
}
```

### In the tf console

```
> jsonencode(split(",", join(",", formatlist("%s/32", var.web_ips), list(var.vpc_cidr), var.allowed_sources, formatlist("%s/32", list(var.vpn_ip)))))
["10.10.0.1/32","10.0.0.0/16","10.0.0.1/32","10.0.0.2/32","10.11.0.1"/32"]

> split(",", join(",", formatlist("%s/32", var.web_ips), list(var.vpc_cidr), var.allowed_sources, formatlist("%s/32", list(var.vpn_ip))))
[
  "10.10.0.1/32",
  "10.0.0.0/16",
  "10.0.0.1/32",
  "10.0.0.2/32",
  "10.11.0.1"/32",
]
```

When passing JSON (${local.ips1}), I get:

```
Error: Error running plan: 1 error(s) occurred:

* aws_s3_bucket_policy.bucket: "policy" contains an invalid JSON: invalid character '1' after object key:value pair
```

When pass a list I get:

```
Error: aws_s3_bucket_policy.bucket
: 1 error occurred:
    * aws_s3_bucket_policy.bucket: At column 1, line 1: output of an HIL expression must be a string, or a single list (argument 2 is TypeList) in:

{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Id": "Policy0000000000000",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Sid": "Stmt0000000000000",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Principal": "*",
            "Action": "s3:*",
            "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::bucket/*",
            "Condition": {
                "IpAddress": {
                    "aws:SourceIp": "${local.ips2}"
              }
            }
        },
        {
            "Sid": "Stmt00000000000",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Principal": "*",
            "Action": "s3:*",
            "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::bucket/*",
            "Condition": {
                "StringEquals": {
                    "aws:SourceVpc": "vpc-000000000000"
                }
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Yeah, so after battling with this for a while, the JSON solution would've have worked but I stuffed it up (as my colleague Doug pointed out) with putting double quotes around the variable within the policy like you can see in the last code snippet ("${local.ips2}")
Here's the working config:

```
locals {

ips = "${jsonencode(split(",", join(",", formatlist("%s/32", var.web_ips), list(var.vpc_cidr), var.allowed_sources, formatlist("%s/32", list(var.vpn_ip)))))}"
}

resource "aws_s3_bucket_policy" "bucket" {
  bucket = "${aws_s3_bucket.bucket.id}"

  policy = <<POLICY
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Id": "Policy000000000000",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Sid": "Stmt00000000000",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Principal": "*",
            "Action": "s3:*",
            "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::bucket/*",
            "Condition": {
                "IpAddress": {
                    "aws:SourceIp": ${local.ips} <<<< NO QUOTES HERE!
              }
            }
        },
        {
            "Sid": "Stmt0000000000",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Principal": "*",
            "Action": "s3:*",
            "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::bucket/*",
            "Condition": {
                "StringEquals": {
                    "aws:SourceVpc": "vpc-00000000000"
                }
            }
        }
    ]
}
POLICY
}
```

Hope this helps anyone out there